# How to trigger multiple builds for RC branches

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In TFS, for every release we create RC branches on the 15 TFS repos. For every RC created I have to manually start a build for the branch. I want to automate this process.

I tried to setup new Builds with CI Trigger based on RC*. However, these are only triggered when something in pushed into the branch, not when it's created.

Is there any way to accomplish this in TFS? Is there a way to submit multiple builds at the same time instead of doing them 1 by 1. I thought I could put then in a folder and submit entire folder for build but this is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to accomplish this in TFS?

The answer is **yes**. You could set the wildcard `*` in the Branch filters:

[image]

In this case, all of branches under the folder `RcBranch` can trigger a build including create a new branch under the folder `RcBranch`, for example, `RcBranch/Vesion1`.

**Note**: To set the `RcBranch/*`, select the drop list->All branches->Input `RcBranch/*`.

> Is there a way to submit multiple builds at the same time instead of
>   doing them 1 by 1

The answer is also yes.

You could create a new blank build pipeline, let us call it to `TriggerBuild`. When we setup any new build, we could add TriggerBuild build as **build completion**:

[image]

Now, if we want to submit multiple builds at the same time, we could execute the build `TriggerBuild`, after it completed, other builds will be triggered.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have setup the build trigger based on the branch name RC*. However, the build will only trigger if something is pushed into the branch. This would not be the case. We are creating RC branches off integration and then build them to push artifacts into our CD pipeline.

Comment: @Dmitriy, Not the `RC*`, set `RC/*`. Don't ignore slashes. That means all branches from RC folder. Then create a new branch with name `RC/<YourBranchName>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. With your help I was able to figure it out. It's worth pointing out that trigger is case sensitive, so RC* is not the same as rc*